# Google App signing - not able to upload encrypted private key

Tags: android, google-play, certificate, apk, android-app-signing

I have old android app which i want to upgrade on play store. I have correct keystore file and password. as i did not enroll to app signing key so now i have to for upgrade app.
I am trying to follow the steps as mention in app signing console and able to generate private key. when try to upload key, giving me below error
[image]

I contact Google support and they just provided me https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/answers-to-common-questions-about-app-signing-by-google-play-b28fef836af0 document and repeated the same thing again and again.

I already verified my signed apk using `apksigner verify -print-certs -v package.apk`

Simply they say after 2-3 days of conversation, they can not do anything as provided above URL to figure you out.

I have so many apps which I am maintaining and 80% of apps are able to enroll for app signing but only 3-4 apps, are giving the same type of problem.

Comment: What Java version do you use to run pepk.jar? May this has an impact on the created `encrypted_private_key_path`file?

Comment: I solved my problem. The problem was that need to download java from https://www.openlogic.com/openjdk-downloads?page=1 instead of oracle's official website .. even though I was using the latest java 17.0.7 but still needed to download from the openjdk to solve it.